# Angular html directive execution

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I'm building a web application that's fetching data from a backend. Right now the html code looks like this:

```
<div ng-app="App" ng-controller="controller">

    <form ng-submit="getValues()">
        <div>
            <button type="submit">Select</button>
        </div>
    </form>

    <plot-chart value="data"></plot-chart>

</div>
```

and the javascript code looks like this:

```
angular.module('App', [])
.controller('controller', function controller ($scope, $http) {

    $scope.getValues = function () {
        //value getter when submit is pressed 
        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url:"SOME_URL_HERE" + 
                "SOME_PARAM" +
                $scope.some_param.some_id +
                '&OTHER_PARAM=' +
                $scope.other_param.other_id +
                '&group=' +  some_group_id
        }).success(function (data) {
            $scope.data = data;

            if($scope.data == "null"){
                $scope.error = data.message;
                // clear the data part
                $scope.data = '';
                return;
            }

            // clear the error messages
            $scope.error = '';
        }).error(function (data) {
            $scope.error = data.message;
            // clear the data part
            $scope.data = '';
            return;
        }); 
    };

});

.directive("plotChart", function (data) {
    //Graphing values with D3.js that I got from the getter above 
});
```

I want my html document to call on the "makeprettygraph" directive and first clear any old graph and then plot a new graph on the page when I submit the form, but I'm lost as how to make the html do this.

So my question now is the following: What code do I need to implement to make the html document look to the "makeprettygraph"-directive when the submit button is pressed? How do I "connect" the button to the action that draws the graph?

Comment: Your $http call could be simplified by using the [$http.get-shortcut](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#get)

Comment: The simplification wont have any impact on the graphing part though which is what I'm having problems with :-/

Comment: you can't inject your `data` into the directive function (unless it was a service which in this case it isn't). Set up `scope` in the directive to bind to the data passed in `value` attribute. Suggest going through some directive tutorials. Also there are charting directives available already you can use for this

Comment: Does not your controller name right? It's declared as 'AppCtrl' in your javascript but in html as 'controller' in body tag.

Comment: I'm building off existing code and I've neither changed the $http part nor the plotting part. It used to plot exactly what I told it to.. Are you sure? @charlietfl

Comment: @RicardoPontual I tried to make the code as general as possible in the question. It's an artifact from the copy/paste!

Comment: Suggest you make a demo. Your directive is empty so not sure at all what your issue is. As it stands now would throw error `unknown provider dataProvider`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. It was simply a matter of directive naming - it's supposed to be named makePrettyGraph in the angular code, whilst in the HTML code it's make-pretty-graph.

It now executes just fine, even with the val="data" and correctly plots the graph.